# How to deal with interface overuse in TDD?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, interface, tdd

I've noticed that when I'm doing TDD it often leads to a very large amount of interfaces. For classes that have dependencies, they are injected through the constructor in the usual manner:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass(IDependencyA first, IDependency second)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The result is that almost every class will implement an interface.

Yes, the code will be decoupled and can be tested very easily in isolation, but there will also be extra levels of indirection that just makes me feel a little...uneasy. Something doesn't feel right.

Can anyone share other approaches that doesn't involve such heavy use of interfaces?

How are the rest of you guys doing?

Comment: Not sure if the question can be answered as it stands... I see interfaces are roles that need to be met by actual implementations/classes. e.g. For 'me' to 'reach office quickly' I need a 'medium of transport' and a 'optimal path finder'. The interfaces are also boundaries separating 2 layers. Thus the interfaces help you identify which roles are needed and also to assign them clear discrete responsibilities. Don't see a way to avoid it if you want to test each class in isolation (without its dependencies) ; you may want to review your roles and responsibilities though

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your tests are telling you to redesign your classes.

There are times when you can't avoid passing complex collaborators that need to be stubbed to make your classes testable, but you should look for ways to provide them with the *outputs* of those collaborators instead and think about how you could re-arrange their interactions to eliminate complex dependencies.

For example, instead of providing a `TaxCalculator` with a `ITaxRateRepository` (that hits a database during `CalculateTaxes`), obtain those values before creating your `TaxCalculator` instance and provide them to its constructor:

```
// Bad! (If necessary on occasion)
public TaxCalculator(ITaxRateRepository taxRateRepository) {}

// Good!
public TaxCalculator(IDictonary<Locale, TaxRate> taxRateDictionary) {}
```

Sometimes this means you have to make bigger changes, adjust object lifetimes or restructure large swaths of code, but I've often found low-lying fruit once I started looking for it.

For an excellent roundup of techniques for reducing your dependency on dependencies, see [Mock Eliminating Patterns](http://simpleprogrammer.com/2011/01/26/back-to-basics-mock-eliminating-patterns/).

Comment: I really like the link you posted.

Answer (score 7):

Don't use interfaces! Most mocking frameworks can mock concrete classes.

Comment: Are you saying that I should inject concrete classes instead of interfaces?

Comment: Why not? There's little point in creating an interface that only has one implementation in the production code if the only reason you're creating it is so that you can mock it.

Comment: So instead I should make the methods in those concrete classes virtual in order to mock them, is that it?

Comment: You haven't specifically said you're using Java, but since you mention interfaces, I assumed you are. In which case, all (non-static) methods in Java are virtual already.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to tag with C#. Fixed.

Comment: :-) So, if you were using Java... ;-)

Comment: In c# it is still better to declare virtual methods, than create redundant interfaces. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90851/is-creating-interfacesfor-almost-every-class-justified-or-are-interfaces-overus?lq=1

Answer (score 3):

That's the drawback of mock based testing approaches. This is as much a test boundary discussion as it is about mocking. By having a 1:1 ratio of test cases to domain classes your test boundary is very small. A result of a small test boundary is a proliferation of interfaces and tests that depend on them. Refactoring becomes more difficult due to the number of interactions you are mocking and stubbing out. By testing clusters of classes with a single test, refactoring becomes easier and you use fewer interfaces. Beware, however that you can test too many classes at once. The more complexity your classes have, the more code paths you need to test. This can lead to a combinatorial explosion and you can't possibly test them all. Listen to the code and tests, they're telling you something about your code. If you see the complexity increasing, it's probably a good time to introduce a new Test Case and Interface/Implementation and mock it out in your original.

Comment: If I test several classes in one test then I suppose those classes should relate to the same feature. One example is when class A uses class B + class C, and both are helper classes. Should I inject B and C into A or could I let A instantiate them?

Comment: My style would be to instantiate them in the constructor so you can make them injectable with a simple Introduce Parameter refactoring if you decide to test the A, B, and C classes independently later. DI is a good thing, but it can still be YAGNI.

Comment: Your considerations are about when to use mocks/stubs. It doesn't prove that interfaces are required for mocking. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90851/is-creating-interfacesfor-almost-every-class-justified-or-are-interfaces-overus?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

If you are feeling uneasy about the number of interfaces being passed into a particular class; then it is probably a sign that you are introducing too many disparate dependencies.

If *SomeClass* depends on *IDependencyA*, *IDependencyB*, and *IDependencyC*, this is an opportunity to see if you can extract out the logic that the class performs with those three interfaces into another class/interface, *IDependencyABC*.

Then when you are writing your tests for *SomeClass*, you only need to mock out the logic that *IDependencyABC* now provides.

In addition, if you are still uncomfortable; maybe it is not an interface you require.  For example, classes that contain state (parameters being passed around, for instance) could probably just be created and passed around as concrete classes instead.  Jeff's answer alluded to this, where he mentions passing into your constructor ONLY what you need.  This provides less coupling between your constructs and is a better indication of the intent of your class's needs.  Just be careful passing around data structures (IDictionary<,>).

In the end, TDD is working when you get that warm fuzzy feeling during your cycles.  If you feel uneasy, watch for some of the code smells and fix some of those issues to get back on track.

Comment: "Just be careful passing around data structures (IDictionary<,>)."  -  seems like you are advicing against what Jeff is suggesting in his example. Can you explain why passing data structures would be bad?

Comment: There is nothing wrong in general with passing around basic data structures internally to a class.  I find that in public interfaces; however, that this _can_ mask the intent of the method call.  It _may_ be more appropriate to pass in class which models what is required (and it may have a Dictionary internally).  I have on more than a few occasions, had to debug legacy code with many methods passing around HashSets, Dictionaries, and Lists. The intent of all of these were very unclear, since there is minimal context inherent to a basic data structure.

Comment: Ok, now I see what you meant. And I agree, a proper domain object is often better than a primitive data structure.

Comment: Not to drag on the point, but primitive data structures (Dictionaries, Lists, HashSets) are mutable.  That can cause a lot of debugging headaches down the road when passing around mutable structures.